# TableViewCells Array reorders itself after updating TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, queue

**hello my fellow programmer friends,**

i have run into a problem with swift's UITableView and I just can't find the error.

I am pretty expirienced with iOS's TableViews and I know how they use a queue to be as performantly as possible.

I usually just build an array of UITableViewCells in my ViewController and update the TableView based on that array. With this technique, I can use one DataSource Class for all my TableViews, which is very clean and always worked fine.

Until now: 
This is my first TableView with many cells of the same type, which I add new cells to if the user presses on the last cell, a "LoadMore" cell.
But the problem is, if said "LoadMore" cell gets pressed, as soon as the TableView gets updated, the TableView and even the tableViewCells array reorder themselves, and even contain double entries which cannot be presented correctly.

I can't find the reason for this. Everything is normal, and all the data and the tableViewCells array definitely are correct, until TableViews reloadData() gets called. I checked many times now what they contain before and after the update.

Here is the (reduced) code for my ViewController, which by the way only contains the TableView:

```
import UIKit

class UserDataTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //Auto updating TableView
    var tableViewCells = [UITableViewCell]() {
        didSet {
            dataSource.update(with: tableViewCells)
            tableView.reloadData()
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    //DataSource for Table View
    var dataSource = NormalTableDataSource(cells: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //TableView
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorColor = .darkText

        //get next data
        nextData()
    }

    func nextData() {
        if let data = self.data {
            //some code that finds the next data and then calls:
            addDataToTableView(data: nextData, morePages: true)
        }
    }

    func addDataToTableView(data: Array<Any>, morePages: Bool = false) {
        //create temp array out of old tableViewCells array
        var tempCells = tableViewCells

        //remove LoadMore cell if it exists
        if (tempCells.count > 0) {
            tempCells.removeLast()
        }

        //(Rating is a simple Struct)
        if let ratings = data as? [Rating] {
            //This loop runs aprox. 25 times
            for rating in ratings {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserRatedAlbumCell") as! UserRatedAlbumCell
                cell.update(rating: rating)
                tempCells.append(cell)
            }
        }

        //add LoadMore cell
        if (morePages) {
            let loadMoreCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoadMoreCell")!
            tempCells.append(loadMoreCell)
        }

        //update array, which automatically updates the tableView
        self.tableViewCells = tempCells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableViewCells[indexPath.row].frame.size.height
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableViewCells[indexPath.row]

        if (cell.reuseIdentifier == "LoadMoreCell") {
            self.nextData()
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here is the (also a little reduced) code inside the "UserRatedAlbumCell" class:

```
import UIKit

class UserRatedAlbumCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var albumCoverImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumNameLabel: UILabel!

    //data
    var album: Album?
    var rating: Rating?

    func update(rating: Rating) {
        self.rating = rating
        albumNameLabel.text = ""
        albumCoverImage.image = nil

        //---Some async task with completion block that returns "album":
        {
            if let album = album {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.update(album: album, rating: rating)
                }
            }
        }
        //---
    }

    func update(album: Album) {
        self.album = album

        albumNameLabel.text = album.attributes?.name

        if let url = album.attributes?.artwork.url(forWidth: 150) {
            albumCoverImage.downloaded(with: url)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my "NormalTableDataSource", which is, as previously said, used in nearly all of my TableViews:

```
import UIKit

class NormalTableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var cells: [UITableViewCell]?

    init(cells: [UITableViewCell]?) {
        self.cells = cells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cells = cells {
            return cells[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func update(with cells: [UITableViewCell]?) {
        self.cells = cells
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? 
If requested, I can provide screenshots of what happens with the TableView. But I can tell you that, as soon as LoadMore gets pressed the first time, all cells reorder themselves and there are many blank cells, probably caused by double entry's in the tableViewCells array.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This *seems* very wrong. In general, you track changes in your **data** (such as an array of `[Rating]` as you've shown). Then, in `cellForRowAt` you would ***dequeue a reusable cell***. I've never seen the approach of creating cells elsewhere, and trying to hold them in an array,

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` is returning existing cells from your tableview which you're adding back in to the array, that's why you're seeing duplicate rows. I think you need to go back and look at how to properly dequeue cells.

Comment: This approach is fraught with issues.  Apple provides a mechanism designed for deploying tableViews - as @JamesP says, you should very strongly consider using it.

Comment: Oh ok, good to know. I once just had the idea of doing it how I did it, and it worked fine in simpler tableViews, so I never considered it as faulty.

Comment: I will have a look at the docs again. Never thought that dequeuing a reusable cell in another place then the datasource could be a problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short dequeueReusableCell is intended to be called from 'tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)' which is why you are having issues.

A more elaborated story is that it returns cells which table view itself considers to be no longer used, the fact that you store references to these cells somewhere (like your tableViewCells property) doesn't change anything, the table view still has every right to reuse those cells whenever it makes sense to it. So each time you call nextData() you get duplicated cells.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that. Thanks!